# Showing users only their information

Tags: php, database, foreign-key-relationship

Okay so im new to databases, and have created a site with a users table, and i also hace a list table, where suers can insert list items, however when they log in everyones list is appearing, how can i link the user table to the lists table, is it creating the same field in each one and using a foreign key? Sorry I am very new to this. Appreciate any help

Comment: What do your table structures look like? You're right in thinking to use a foreign key, have you tried to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use user_id on both tables to fix this. Let me give an example:

Table A (user_id, username, password)

Table B (list_item_id, user_id , any_other_attribute)

When you design your tables like this a simple sql call will do what you need like:

SELECT 'list_item_id','any_other_attribute' FROM Table B Where user_id=$user_id

Where $user_id is the user_id of the one's who loginned your system.

Also by your question, i suggest you to read about these : 'sessions' , 'sql queries' , 'generating sql query results' on your choice of programming language.

Answer (score 0):

It calls MANY MANY relationnship. There mus be 1 table with fields user_id and field_id that will join this 2 tables